# Change request_timeout_in_seconds in Pivotal Web Services

Tags: cloud-foundry, haproxy, pivotal-web-services

We have deployed an application on [run.pivotal.io](https://run.pivotal.io).

The default value for `request_timeout_in_seconds` is 900 seconds which is 15 minutes and too short for our use case. How can we change that?

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/blob/master/jobs/gorouter/spec#L105

The application is using the node.js 1.5.5 buildpack on the cflinuxfs2 stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a system-level configuration that you cannot change in Pivotal Web Services, because Pivotal Web Services is a hosted deployment of Cloud Foundry.  If you deployed your own Cloud Foundry (or paid for a vendor to help you deploy) you could configure this parameter.

You may want to share your feedback with [Pivotal Web Services support](https://support.run.pivotal.io/home), if this is a common enough request amongst many customers, they may consider re-tuning that parameter.

Comment: Which pretty much means Pivotal Web Services are unsuitable if you're planning to create an application where people download/upload bigger files, potentially over a slow connection, where they easily could hit the 15 minutes boundry.